# Using parseval's theory to calculate energy of signal $f(t)=e^{-t}H(t-\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: fourier-analysis

So yeah, I have
$f(t)=e^{-t}H(t-\frac{1}{2})$ and I want to calculate its energy and what $\omega$ range holds 95% of the signal's total energy. I know that I'm probably going to use Parseval and time shift to make the function integral range from $0$ to $inf$, but I'm not quite sure as to how.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|^2 dt = \int_{1/2}^\infty e^{-2t}dt = \, ?$ Then what did you find for $\hat{f}(\omega)$ ?

Comment: Energy at $E=\frac{1}{2e}-\frac{1}{2}$ and FT $\frac{ie^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\omega}}{\omega -i}$

Comment: E at $\frac{1}{2e}$ I mean

Comment: So that $|\hat{f}(\omega)|^2 = ?$ and $\int_{-A}^A |\hat{f}(\omega)|^2 d\omega = ?$